# Find an equation for the exponential function with points $(0, \sqrt{2})$ and $(3,4)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am attempting to answer this question from my textbook:
[image]

Using two coordinates, one of which being the y intercept, I am reading these two points from the graph:
$(0,\sqrt{2})$ and $(3,4)$

The solution is:
$f(x)=\sqrt{2}(\sqrt{2})^x$.

I am struggling to arrive at this expression. My working:

$$y=ab^x$$
$$a=\sqrt{2}$$
$$4=\sqrt{2}b^3$$
$$b^3=\frac{4}{\sqrt{2}}$$

From here, I do not know where to go. I'm less concerned about the solution as the steps I need to learn to get there. Granular baby steps really appreciated here.

I could take the above steps a step further with $b=\sqrt[3]{2\sqrt{2}}$ but then I do not know how to simplify this any further.

Once I have isolated $b$, I need to express in terms of $y=ab^x$ and since I already know $a=\sqrt{2}$ it will look like $y=\sqrt{2}b^x$. I just need to know how to simplify my working for $b$ so that I can arrive at $f(x)=\sqrt{2}(\sqrt{2})^x$

Comment: $2\sqrt 2 = 2^1 \times 2^{1/2} = 2^{3/2}$, or $4/\sqrt 2 = 2^2 \div 2^{1/2} = 2^{3/2}$. Now take the cube root, which is $(2^{3/2})^{1/3}$.

Comment: Write 4 as a multiplication of four radical 2's

Comment: Clearly $f(x)=\sqrt2b^x$.  Now we have to reach $4$ by multiplying $\sqrt2$ thrice with the same number, which is obviously $\sqrt2$, too.

Comment: $b^3=2\sqrt2=\sqrt2\times\sqrt2\times\sqrt2=\sqrt2^3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If
$$b^3={4\over\sqrt2}$$
then cube root both sides.
$$b={\sqrt[3]4\over\sqrt[3]{\sqrt2}}$$
Now, to simplify.
$4$ can be represented as $2^2$
So, $\sqrt[3]4$ can be represented as $\sqrt[3]{2^2}$.

The bottom is similar!
$\sqrt[3]{\sqrt2}$ -> $\sqrt[6]2$

So we get the fraction
$${\sqrt[3]{2^2}}\over{\sqrt[6]2}$$
Gross. Radicals in the denominator. If we multiply $\sqrt[6]2$ by $\sqrt[6]{2^5}$, we get $\sqrt[6]{2^6}$, or $2$. Nice! Just need to do the same thing to the numerator. $\sqrt[3]{2^2}*\sqrt[6]{2^5}=2^{2\over3}*2^{5\over6}=2^{{2\over3}+{5\over6}}=2^{9\over6}=2^{3\over2}={\sqrt2}^3=2{\sqrt2}$

Therefore,
$$b={{2\sqrt2}\over{2}}$$
The $2$s cancel, resulting in
$$b=\sqrt2$$
And the final equation is
$$f(x)=\sqrt2(\sqrt2)^x$$

But that was all from scratch. You mentioned that you managed to get
$$b={\sqrt[3]{2\sqrt2}}$$
From there, you can recognise that $2\sqrt{2}=\sqrt{2}^3$ (because 2 is the same as $\sqrt2*\sqrt2$). So,
$$b={\sqrt[3]{{\sqrt2}^3}}$$
The $\sqrt[3]{ }$ and $^3$ cancel, leaving you with just
$$b=\sqrt2$$